# Using -eq across two datasets in powershell

Tags: powershell, datatable, dataset, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm in a juncture here. I have two datasets in powershell. Dataset 1(**$table**) is received via an sql query *(varies from 12 to 17 rows and has 8 columns)* and Dataset 2(**$team**) is hard coded in the script *(has 18 rows and 2 columns)*. Both of these have a common column, **Contest**. Now the script I have to get working is - for each *Contest* in **$table.contest**, get other corresponding parameters from **$table** and match the *Contest* in **$team.contest** and get the corresponding **$team.column2** value into play.

I'm able to get the data individually from each table, but when I use "-eq" condition across **$table.contest** & **$team.contest**, nothing happens.

This is the snippet from the code where I'm facing the problem.

```
$Contests = ($DataSet.Contest)
$Team     = ($Team.cont)

foreach($Contest in $Contests)
{
    $ContestName = $Contest
    $stats       = $DataSet | where {$_.contest -eq $contest}
    $signups     = $stats.SignUps
    $newbies      = $stats.Newbies
    $uploads     = $stats.Uploads
    $views       = $stats.Views
    $eviews      = $stats.EViews
    $votes       = $stats.Votes
    $date        = $stats.EndDate
    $teamx       = $team | where {$_ -eq $stats.contest}
    $contest
    $teamx
    }
```

$contest shows the contest name, but $teamx is blank

The following is the changed code with respect hash tables. I tried to convert object array to string but in vain.

```
$team = @{
"Short Film" = "Member4";
"Student Photography" = "Member0";
"Student Art" = "Member1";
"Macro Photography" = "Member2";
"Landscape Photography" = "Member3";
}

$Contests = ($DataSet.Contest)
$Contests = $Contests | where {$_ -ne "" -and $_ -ne $null -and $_ -ne [dbnull]::value}

foreach($Contest in $Contests)
{
    $ContestName = $Contest
    $stats       = $DataSet | where {$_.contest -eq $contest}
    $signups     = $stats.SignUps
    $datatemp    = $stats.Contest
    if ($team.ContainsKey($datatemp)) {write-output "Exists"}
    else {write-output "Doesn't Exist"}
    $datatemp
    $team.count
    }
```

I tried directly feeding *$Contest*, *$ContestName*, and *$stast.Contest* inside **ContainsKey**, but all the time output is the same -

```
Doesn't Exist
Short Film
5
Doesn't Exist
Student Photography
5
Doesn't Exist
Student Art
5
Doesn't Exist
Macro Photography
5
Doesn't Exist
Landscape Photography
5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of ` $stats.contest` cause I'm guessing that it is an object array and not a string. `[string]$stats.contest` is what happens behind the scenes in order for the comparison to work. Also if there is no match in `$team` then it would return null as well. We can't recreate you issue which might be a problem.

Comment: You can't compare two arrays with -eq.  From the description of the problem, I'd start by trading that $team dataset for a hash table, using Contest as the key and whatever that other column is as the value.

Comment: @Matt. Yes you are right. $stats is an object array. I'll use string and see if it'll work.

Comment: @mjolinor. I will use hash operation and see if it'll work.

Comment: If you haven't used hash tables before, prepare for an epiphany.

Comment: @mjolinor. I have updated the code using Hash Tables and edited the post with the output and issues.

Comment: @mjolinor. I used the trim() operation to remove the trailing space. One thing is troubling me. I checked where the trailing space is being generated and found out that _$stats.contest_ is adding an extra space at the end. In fact each of the _$stats.<variable name>_  and each element in _$contests_ is having an extra space. It'd be great if you can throw light on this and how it can be prevented.

Comment: I don't know what might cause that offhand.  $stats is just a subset of $DataSet, which is kind of a "black box" based on the information available in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell for sure without knowing exactly what's in $Dataset, but your symptoms all point to trailing whitespace in the Contest value that's causing your tests to fail.

Try this and see if you get different results:

```
foreach($Contest in $Contests)
{
    $ContestName = $Contest
    $stats       = $DataSet | where {$_.contest -eq $contest}
    $signups     = $stats.SignUps
    $datatemp    = $stats.Contest.trim()
    if ($team.ContainsKey($datatemp)) {write-output "Exists"}
    else {write-output "Doesn't Exist"}
    $datatemp
    $team.count
    }
```